# is it correct to use (word) + の逆? to express "the opposite of..."

Tags: word-requests

I was trying to come up with a way to say "the opposite of (word)" and since I already knew about 逆 in my head I thought it'd make sense to use a word + の逆 but I'm not 100% sure if that's correct.
Ex: the opposite of short 短いの逆

Answer (score 1):

I would usually use `「〇〇の反対」` to express the idea of `'the opposite of 〇〇'`.

Looking at it another way, you can use the word `反対語` to mean `antonym` (e.g. if you are using an online thesaurus to search for the same).